# Sorting data by association?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

That title may have been misleading, I don't know quite how to put it.
I have a set of data where a number stands for a description. It currently looks like this:

```
10 Blue
11 Green
12 Purple
13 Red
14 Orange
```

With the numbers in one column and the descriptions in an adjacent column. 
I have a third column (same worksheet but separate) populated with these numbers in a specific order, like so:

```
13
12
12
10
11
10
etc.
```

Instead of filling in each description by hand, is there a way I can "associate" the data (for lack of better words) and auto fill the blank column next to my numbers with the correct description?

For example: the number 16 correlates with Grey, is there a way I can take the first set of columns and set up the third column so that every time 16 appears, the cell next to it will fill out with "Grey"?
Let me know if I need to explain further, any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Check out VLOOKUP or INDEX and MATCH.  They do exactly that.

Comment: Now that you know, you will need to change your user name.  :-)

Comment: Oh don't worry, something else will come up I'm sure :)